# Convert an array of String to array of float in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, string, swift

I am building an iOS application using Swift Language. Inside my ViewController2, i have an array of String. How do i convert this array of String to an array of Float value? toPass1 stores numerical values that user enters through the UITextField.

```
var toPass1 = [String]()
var force = [Float] ()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an alternative:

```
var toPass : [String] = ["21.0","3.12","23"]
var force = [Float]()

for item in toPass {
    force.append((item as NSString).floatValue)
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can do this

```
var toPass1 : [String] = ["1.0","2.90","23"]

var force = toPass1.map{
    ($0 as NSString).floatValue
}
```

Comment: It gives an error stating that ViewController does not have a member named 'toPass1'  Part of the code is here [link] (https://github.com/cherrythia/arraystringstoarrayfloat)

Answer (score 1):

```swift
let toPass = ["1.2", "-15", "4.137e+02"]
let force = toPass.map { Float($0)! }
```